# swift: how to assign a string from textField to another string?

Tags: string, swift, assign

swift: how to assign a string from textField to another string ?

for example:

if user writes in the texField "abc" i want the program/app to output "DoReMi"

```
a=Do  
b=Re  
c=Mi
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
let inputString = "abc"
// create a dictionary with your notes
let notes = ["a":"Do","b":"Re","c":"Mi","d":"Fa","e":"So","f":"La","g":"Ti"]
// map the value of your string characters keys
let output = "".join( Array(inputString).map{ notes[ String($0) ] ?? "" } )
println(output)   // "DoReMi"
```

If you want it to happen as the user type, you just need to addTarget to your textField for the control event editing changed as follow:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    let notes = ["a":"Do","b":"Re","c":"Mi","d":"Fa","e":"So","f":"La","g":"Ti"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.addTarget(self, action: "editingChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func editingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        sender.text = sender.text!.notesOnly
         label.text = String(Array(textField.text!.characters).map{ self.notes[ String($0) ] ?? "" })
    }

}

extension String {
    var notesOnly: String {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefg").invertedSet).joinWithSeparator("")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question: you want to be able to take in a string and then output a string based on what the user types in, is this correct? You can accomplish this with dictionaries. At the top of your view controller file add a variable like so:

```
var myDic = ["a":"Do", "b":"Re", "c":"Mi"]
```

and then all you have to do is check each character in the text field's string, which might look kind of like this:

```
let stringArr = Array(textField.text)
var outStr = ""
for char in stringArr {
    if let c = myDic[String(char)] {
        outStr = outStr + c
    }
}
println(outStr)
```